# Can't connect to 192.168.1.1

Tags: ip

I'm trying to change the password on my router. I looked up how to do this and I need to connect to 192.168.1.1 but whenever I try to I get an error 404. I tried to ping it and that worked just fine.  So how can I get the web browser to connect to 192.168.1.1?

Comment: What model router is it?

Comment: Smart rg SR350NE.

Comment: Try factory resetting the router.

Comment: Have you verified that your default gateway is actually 192.168.1.1 and not something else?

Comment: I already verified that.

Comment: What happens if you type this in: http://192.168.1.1/admin thats the direct link to the admin page for your model

Comment: How sure are you that 192.168.1.1 is the IP of your router and not of another (or even your) device on the network? What is your IP? What is the IP of the gateway?

Comment: try this address:  routerlogin.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to 192.168.1.1/admin as mentioned in the comments and then it connected to 192.168.1.1 exactly like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check.

First make sure that the ip address is correct. Assuming you are already connected to the router, this will normally be your "default gateway" address. In Windows, open command prompt and type `ipconfig` and verify that the default gateway is 192.168.1.1

Also post the output of ipconfig in your question.

If it is not correct, use the ip listed as the default gateway instead.

If it is correct, verify that your PC's ip address is on the same subnet as the router (I.e. 192.168.1.xxx),  restart the router (power cycle it) and try again.

Still nothing? Restart your PC and try again.

Still nothing? Factory reset the router and try again.